# Redirects from Tumblr to new WP

Tags: redirect, migration, tumblr

I migrated a site from Tumblr to WordPress and was able to get all the content over (in pieces) using the FeedWordPress plugin. What I am now trying to do is get the old permalink structure to redirect dynamically.

The plugin added a custom field with the old Tumblr permalink (syndication_permalink is the name of the field). Is there a function I can write using wp_redirect to check for this field, and if so redirect to the new permalink URL?

Answer (score 1):

Hey, you might have luck with a [prior plugin I wrote](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cp-redirect/) ([here's the code itself](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/cp-redirect/trunk/cp-redirect.php)). It's a redirect plugin that looks at the URL coming in, checks it against the postmeta table if it's about to produce a 404, and redirect the user if a match is found.

If you have the entire URI stored in the custom field for a post, it might look something like:

```
/**
 * Redirect old Tumblr URLs to new WP if the URI exists in the database
 */
function tumblr_legacy_redirect() {
    global $wpdb; // We're going to use this for the db lookup

    // Only run this lookup on URLs that are going to 404 anyway
    if ( is_404() ) {

        // We're getting the incorrect URI in hopes that it's an old Tumblr link
        $requested_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        // Prepare the query so we protect ourselves against bad SQL queries
        $query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='syndication_permalink' AND meta_value='%s'", $requested_url );
        $post_id = $wpdb->get_results( $query, 'ARRAY_N' );
        // Catch if there are duplicate results in the database
        $post_id = $post_id[0][0];

        // Build the redirect if the post_id exists
        if ( $new_url = get_permalink( $post_id ) ) {
            wp_redirect( $new_url, 301 );
        } else {
            return;
        }

   } // END - if ( is_404() )

} // END - tumblr_legacy_redirect()

// A good place for our template redirect to hook into
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'tumblr_legacy_redirect' );
```

Caveat is that I haven't actually tested the code, so let me know if you run into any errors!

Comment: Hmmmm..doesn't seem to work. When I drop in the function as-is, any of the old Tumblr URLs redirect back to the homepage. When I remove the meta_value="$article_id" portion (since i don't see that mentioned anywhere else in the function) they all seem to redirect back to one post (regardless)

Comment: @Daniel: You store the request URI in `$request_uri`, but in the `prepare()` you write `$requested_url`. Also, you prepare the statement but it contains no `%s`, only `'$article_id'`. Shouldn't that line look like this: `$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='syndication_permalink' AND meta_value=%s", $request_uri );`?

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the catch, I've updated the snippet.

Comment: @Norcross Sorry, I made a couple of typos. Please try it now and let us know how it works

Comment: Still no luck. At the end of the query, the meta_value = shouldn't that be the old Tumblr URL?

Comment: Yes, meta_value is using the incoming URI to search for your post_id by matching what you have in your custom field. Can you include a sample syndication_permalink value? We may have to trim the request URI.

Comment: Here's an example in the syndication_permalink field  http://theantisocialmedia.com/post/1581205020

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was the entire URL. I've changed the lookup to be based on the entire URL. `$requested_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` Try the code snippet now?